# How to write an XSLT to take an element out of an element?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml as this;

```
<root>
    <a>
        <a1>value</a1>
        <a2>value</a2>
        <b>
            <b1>value</b1>
            <b2>value</b2>
        </b>
    </a>
</root>
```

I simply want to take the element b out of the element a; which means I need the following result xml.

```
<root>
    <a>
        <a1>value</a1>
        <a2>value</a2>
    </a>
    <b>
        <b1>value</b1>
        <b2>value</b2>
    </b>
</root>
```

What would be the best way to handle this in an XSLT?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways you could approach this / which you take depends on your exact requirements.  The code below will find any element `a`, and will copy it removing any immediate child elements `b` from under it, then will put them immediately after the original `a`.

```
<xsl:template match="//a">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="./*[not(local-name()='b')]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="./b"/>
</xsl:template>
```

---

## Update per comments

If handling multiple sub elements, you can handle like so

```
<xsl:template match="//a">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="./*[not(local-name()='b') and not(local-name()='c')]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="./b"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="./c"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This works for the scenario. However my requirement goes a little beyond this too. If there was another element as c (within a) then I cannot repeat the process to take both elements b and c out of a can I? I tried but failed. That means, the solution worked for only one element.

Comment: You should be able to handle that scenario; see update above.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way to achieve the desired result would be to have an excluding template to match `b` under `a` and explictly adding at the desired location:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:element name="root">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
            <xsl:element name="b">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="a/b/*" />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a/b" />

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```